# Problem with decrreasing sequence of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $X$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $f: X\rightarrow X$-a linear mapping.
We have then decreasing sequence of subspaces $(Im f^k)_{k\in \mathbb N}$.

How to prove that if for some $n\in \mathbb N$

$Im f^n=Im f^{n+1}$ then $Im f^{n+1}=Im f^{n+2}$.

Comment: Look at the sequence of dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f^{n+2}(X)=f\circ f^{n+1}(X)=$??

(Note that Im($f^n)=f^n({X})$)